# how to replace Http with https in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have custom domain and i am using blogger as host 
recently i try to use cloudflare flexible ssl
now everything is ok 
i just need to replace my http link to https like this site

```
https://www.bloggerguider.com
```

i have this javascript code that works with jquery but it,s only change  head links of my site to https .
i just wonder should i make some change to this javascript code or maybe i should use another javascript beside this
thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").each(function() {
var i = $(this).attr("href");
var n = i.replace("http://www.yourblog", "https://www.yourblog");
$(this).attr("href", function() {
return n
})
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with javascript? You realize it'll still result in errors due to images and assets loading from http rather than https, even if you change the src attribute with javascript?

Comment: because i am using blogger as host and this is only way for replacing http to https

Comment: Use my updated answer.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I just googled "SSL blogger" and I got a bunch of articles on how to solve problem X.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(key, val){
         $(val).attr('href', $(val).attr('href').replace("http://www.yourblog", "https://www.yourblog"));
    });
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0voh7w3m/)

Comment: thanks mojtaba but still the same only the head part of my domain get https

Comment: @daniyal62, it's working fine. Check out the demo I put in the answer